# How to get name from database ?

Tags: android, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to get name from database and display in textview. It is working fine when my application is already installed, but when the application is uninstalled and installed again then it's giving `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Here is my code:

```
if(c.getString(0)==null){
    TextView w1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textVi1);
    w1.setText("Welcome");
} else {
    TextView w1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textVi1);
    w1.setText("Welcome"+" "+c.getString(0)+",");
}
```

How should I fetch the data when the application is uninstalled and reinstalled?

Comment: Maybe your `cursor` is empty and so you can't pull a `getString(0)` (get first element) on an empty list.

Comment: May be cursor is null,can't determine from this. post your code and stack trace.

Comment: so how to overcome this problem..

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundException at 0th location simple means that your fetched result is empty, or may be your cursor is not moved to first . Check it out yourself, or just post your code here, we'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It may helpful.

```
public String getResult(String id)
{
    String name = null;
    try
    {
        Cursor c = null;
        c = db.rawQuery("select name from person where id=" + "\""+id+"\"", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        c.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `getString()` on the cursor, make sure it points to a valid row:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
  // use c.getString(0)
} else {
  // don't access cursor, no data
}
```